# How to send analytics event in android when app is closed

Tags: android

I want to send firebase analytics event when user will close the app after using it for sometime, what code i can write to handle this use case

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, we can not tell when the user has pressed the "HOME" button on his device to close the app.

The only thing I can think of is you can write your code in onDestroy() or onStop() function of your Activity.